# initialize onsenui after document loaded

Tags: onsen-ui

i´m trying to initialize onsenui after some js files are loaded, but then
ons.bootstrap() is causing the errors.
when i´m using a sample from onsenui everything is working quite good, but in my 
project, i have to load the js files dynamically and synchronously 
and then ons.bootstrap(); give me the this error 
"'AppController' is not a function, got undefined"

if same js libs in same order are declared in html doc with script tags everything is working good.

i´ve found that if the scripts are loading through normal script tags and then i´m waiting till html document is fully loaded and then call ons.bootstrap() through developer tools i got same error.

so the question is how to initlaize onsen ui after document is loaded?
Hope someone can help, I´m not very familiar with angularJS/OnsenUi... first project

thanks

I have create 2 samples to demonstrate my problem.

1. working like onsenui samples.
   `jbBgmd` http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jbBgmd
2. not working like in my case.
   `BoWXdP` http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BoWXdP

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to load Onsen after the elements have been rendered, that's why it gave an error. You should always execute Onsen before the components are rendered.

If you want to execute some code after the DOM has been loaded, you should use `ons.ready()` function, you can take a look at it in the [official documentation](http://onsen.io/guide/overview.html#onsreadyfunction).

Here you can find the fixed and working CodePen: http://codepen.io/andipavllo/pen/ZbKzRy

Here is the edited JS:

```js
ons.bootstrap().controller("appController", function () 
    {
      ons.ready(function(){
      console.log("works")
    })
});
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks a lot, now I know that I have to first initalize UI and then wait till other resources have been loaded.

Comment: @bigdiddy you are welcome, if it solved your issue, please consider to mark the answer as best answer